# Getting message through Apache Camel?

Tags: java, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I have to integrate camel on consumer side of activemq. I have setup activemq and try to configure camel (using java DSL) on consumer language but it does'nt work for me. Here is code:

```
public class TestConsumer {
    static String url = ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL;
    static String subject = "Test-AMQ";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
        //broker.addConnector(url);
        //broker.setBrokerName("localhost");
        broker.start();

        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost?create=false&waitForStart=10000");
        context.addComponent("jms", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));
        context.addRoutes(new Routes());
        context.start();
    }
}

class Routes extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("jms:"+new TestConsumer().subject).process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Camel Test Message: " + arg0.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Do you receive an exception?

Comment: Also `vm://localhost` uses an embedded broker.

Comment: public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Camel Test Message: "+ arg0.toString());

            }
this part does not show message on console.

Comment: But is there actually a message at this queue? If there is no message, then there is no message for `Apache Camel` to consume.

Comment: vm://localhost uses embedded broker, can't get your point.

Comment: yeah there is a message in queue. When i execute this code, its doesn't show me any message and then terminate.

Comment: i fix the problem. problem was in route.
from("jms:"+new TestConsumer().subject).process(/* some process*/), i had not define from where i getting message. i mean from queue or topic. it must be from("jms:queue:"+TestConsumer.subject) but it was from("jms:"+TestConsumer.subject);

Answer (score 4):

An example that works similar to yours.

```
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection;
//import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService;
import org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent;
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

public class TestConsumer {
  static String url = ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL;
  static String subject = "Test-AMQ";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
  //  BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();

  //  broker.start();

    ActiveMQComponent comp = ActiveMQComponent.activeMQComponent("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");
    context.addComponent("jms",comp); 
    context.addRoutes(new Routes());
    context.start();        
}
}

class Routes extends RouteBuilder {
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("jms:"+TestConsumer.subject).process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Camel Test Message: " + arg0.toString());
        }
    });

    from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=2000").setBody(simple("Hello, World")).to("jms:"+TestConsumer.subject);
}
}
```

Not sure how you wanted the setup to work in the end though.
Using the VM transport actually doesn't require you to fire up a dedicated broker, but uses an in VM instance. I simply put a timer route to fire of some sample messages to that ActiveMQ queue, which will be consumed.